# How can I migrate from provider to Getx in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx, flutter-integration-test

How Can I change this code from provider to Getx:

```
return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
  lazy: false,
  create: (BuildContext context) {
    final UserProvider provider =
        UserProvider(repo: repo1, psValueHolder: valueHolder);
    return provider;
  },
```

and also I have some MultiProvider in other place:

```
          child: MultiProvider(
        providers: <SingleChildWidget>[
          ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider?>(
              lazy: false,
              create: (BuildContext context) {
                return UserProvider(
                    repo: userRepository, psValueHolder: valueHolder);
              }),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<DeleteTaskProvider?>(
              lazy: false,
              create: (BuildContext context) {
                deleteTaskProvider = DeleteTaskProvider(
                    repo: deleteTaskRepository, psValueHolder: valueHolder);
                return deleteTaskProvider;
              }),
        ],
```

thank you